# Emulators stopped working, HAXM installed, says it's not

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I have been working for a year or so in Android Studio and recently just grabbed the API 27 image. Once it was downloaded, I noticed I could no longer run any emulators of any sort, including some running right before the download. I can no longer install, uninstall, do anything with HAXM. I get the famous errors:

```
4:53 PM Emulator: Incompatible HAX module version 3,requires minimum version 4

4:53 PM Emulator: No accelerator found.

4:53 PM Emulator: failed to initialize HAX: Invalid argument
```

When I check version in command prompt, I show an installed version.

```
C:\Users\...\Downloads\haxm-windows_v7_0_0>silent_install.bat -v
6.0.3
```

When I try to update in Android Studio, it says updating, then fails saying it can't uninstall the previous version. When I try from the Intel site, it will neither install nor uninstall and the logs are empty.

```
C:\Users\...\Downloads\haxm-windows_v7_0_0>silent_install.bat -u
Failed to uninstall Intel HAXM! For details, please check the installation log "C:\Users\...\Downloads\haxm-windows_v7_0_0\haxm_silent_run.log"!
```

So whatever happened with the download and install of the API 27 version broke all HAXM functionality across my machine. I have no idea how to get it back. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, here's what I did, a variation of some other issues found online:

- Close android studio and for safety sake, deleted images/SDK components from android in the AVD manager and SDK manager
- go to regedit and delete any references to HAXM that you can find (after backup of course)
- restart machine
- install HAXM from Intel's site
- restart machine
- Go to add/remove programs and remove HAXM
- restart machine
- Go to Android studio, install images, install HAXM

It seemed to work then.